# Woocommerce double checkout button after adding terms checkbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Couldn't find anything on Google... Hope someone here knows an solution.

In woocommerce you can add the terms and conditions page in the checkout settings. After that, a checkbox appears on the checkoutpage so the customer needs to accept the terms.

But... in my case, the checkbox AND proceed button appear twice now...

I disabled all plugins, tried another theme, dit all updates. Latest of all.

When I remove the terms in the CMS, the double button dissappears again.

Ideas how to solve this??
Thank you in advance.

Comment: which theme do you use ?

Comment: You should better contact the theme authors threads opening a ticket support, or it comes from some customizations that you have maid before… But nobody can guess the issue you have, with your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... I found out that the terms page gave problems and another page did not.
There was a link to a pdf in the Terms page. When I removed that, the double button problem disappeared. Now I have added a new link and the problem still doensn't appear again..... very strange.